# Java using continue in loop for duplicate string check

Tags: java, json, loops, parsing, continue

I have made this JSON parser, and I want to get a copy of all the different addresses but no repeated addresses (there are many other JSONobjects involved as well). But I keep on getting an error response when I get to `featuresArray.add(i, feature);`. What am I doing wrong here?

```
private static void simpleJSON() throws IOException {
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONArray featuresArray = new JSONArray();
    String check = "check";

    try {

        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(filepath));
        JSONArray jsonarray = (JSONArray) obj;
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.size(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonobject = (JSONObject) jsonarray.get(i);
            String location_name = (String) jsonobject.get("location_name");
            String street_address = (String) jsonobject.get("street_address");
            if (street_address.equals(check)) {
                continue;
            }
            check = street_address;

            Map feature = new LinkedHashMap();
            feature.put("location_name", location_name);
            feature.put("street_address", street_address);
            featuresArray.add(i, feature);
        }
    } catch (ClassCastException c) {
        c.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Here's the javadoc of the method throwing the exception (that you neglected to post): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-int-E-. It explains when the exception is thrown. Read stack traces. Read javadoc. Why don't you just use `add(feature)`? Also, don't use raw types (you should have compiler warnings for that, too).

Comment: which library you are using for parsing is it Gson?

Answer (score 0):

In your case,

```
if (street_address.equals(check)) {
  continue;
}
```

whenever the above block execute, `continue` statement in particular the control jumps to

```
for (....; i++)
```

so the `i` is going tobe incremented.
Now assume i = 1 and the `equals` condition became true then `i` is going to incremented.
then i becomes 2. now suppose `equals` returns false then this statement executes

```
featuresArray.add(i, feature);
```

so, i was 1 and now it is 2, so it skip the index `1` in this case.
That may causes the problem.

You can modify your codition like this:

```
if (street_address.equals(check)) {
  i--;
  continue;
}
```

to counter the increment of index.